# String.length() vs national letters

Tags: c#, string, string-length

So i have a program that works on text and i need to get the length of string.
BUT if in my word i have a national letter the output of length method is not correct. It gets additional +1 for each national letter, so it returns 6 from "qwerty", but 7 if i use "e with a little tail" instead of regular 'e'.

Any ideas how could i fix that?

Also, sorry for descriptions of letters, but i think stackoverflow takes my national symbols as grammar errors and doesn't allow me to post a question :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tells you on the page for [`string.Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) what to do (emphasis mine):

> The Length property returns the number of Char objects in this
>   instance, not the number of Unicode characters. The reason is that *a
>   Unicode character might be represented by more than one Char*. **Use the
>   System.Globalization.StringInfo class to work with each Unicode
>   character instead of each Char**.